# Is it possible to use Super Scrollorama with Zurb Foundation 4?

Tags: plugins, hyperlink, zurb-foundation, superscrollorama

I'm pretty new at this.  I'm trying to use Super Scrollorama with Zurb Foundation 4.  According to:

http://johnpolacek.github.io/superscrollorama/

> First, link to the jQuery CDN and then embed TweenMax.js and SuperScrollorama.

However, I can't seem to get past the first step?  When I try to add Super Scrollorama to a Foundation 4 project, just importing JQuery seems to break Foundation 4.  TweenMax.js links just fine.

I'm using this code to link it:

```
<script src="js/superscrollorama/greensock/TweenMax.min.js" type="text/javascript">  
</script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Any ideas?  Is this possible?  I did a search on Google and there doesn't seem to be any tutorials showing how to use Super Scrollorama with Zurb Foundation 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured it out.

This script link:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Muse appear **BEFORE** the Zurb Foundation 4 script link:

```
<script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script
```

So, the correct implementation would look like this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/foundation.min.js"></script>
```

Such a crazy small, stupid detail cause such a huge waste of time!

If you add the link AFTER, then Zurb Foundation 4 WILL NOT WORK.